# Pandas Row Iteration Query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dummy dataset with me. Let's say df_1

```
Column  x   y
AAA    20   30
BBB    10   50
CCC    60   80
DDD    90   100
PQR    30   40
RST    50   60
UVW    30   40
LMN    20   30
```

Next is another dataset. Let's say this df_2. I have to lookup the column (of df_1) and see the mapping in df_2. Like CCC and DDD are paired. PQR,RST and UVW are paired.

```
Index   0   1   2
1      AAA      
2      BBB      
3      CCC  DDD 
4      XYZ      
5      PQR  RST UVW
```

This is the desired output. Let's say this df_output

```
Ouput         x      y
AAA           20    30
BBB           10    50
CCC+DDD       150   180
PQR+RST+UVW   110   140
LMN           20    30
```

I was exploring iterrows and isin approach of pandas python but unable to come up with the solution. Can anyone help me regarding this

Approach: I was thinking to take each row of df_1 lookup in df_2 and if found add them.

```
Pseudo Code
for i,j in df_1.iterrows():
    if j isin df_2.columns:
       Add
```

Comment: Please include your data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution, in a couple of steps for better clarity:

```
t = df2.melt(id_vars="Index").dropna()
x_y = pd.merge(t, df1, left_on="value", right_on="Column").groupby("Index").sum()

names = pd.DataFrame(df2.drop("Index", axis=1).stack()).reset_index().groupby("level_0")[0].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))
names = df2.melt(id_vars="Index").dropna().groupby("Index")["value"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))

df1_only = pd.merge(df1, t, left_on="Column", right_on = "value", how = "left", indicator=True)
df1_only = df1_only[df1_only._merge == "left_only"]
df1_only = df1_only[["Column", "x", "y"]].rename(columns = {"Column": "value"})

res = pd.concat([names, x_y], axis=1)
res = pd.concat([res, df1_only], axis = 0)
res = res.dropna()

Output: 

         value      x      y
1          AAA   20.0   30.0
2          BBB   10.0   50.0
3      CCC DDD  150.0  180.0
5  PQR RST UVW  110.0  140.0
7          LMN   20.0   30.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Roy2012. What if it's the reverse? I mean lookup the df_2 column (AAA, BBB) in df_1 and see which are paired, if paired add and if not be it as it is and yield the output. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What's the input and the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is the same, and that's what you're getting in my answer. Where's the gap? (BTW, please include both input and expected output **as text** in the question).

Comment: Hi Roy 2012. Apologies for the formatting. Will do the same

Comment: Roy 2012, Done the edits. Thanks in advance for the help and suggestion

Comment: Roy 2012. Extremely sorry again. Is the output matching? I did the terrible mistake in editing. Such a noob I am.

Comment: It seems to me that the output of my code matches your input. Your output contains "LMN", but there's not such row in the input.

Comment: Input is df_1. Mapping is df_2. The output should be having 'LMN' even if it's not in df_2. Let me explain once more. Input is df_1 column. I want to see whether it's there in df_2. If it's paired (CCC,DDD or PQR,RST,UVW) sum them. If not there in df_2, return as it is (like 'LMN')

Comment: Great. It would be nice if you accepted my answer for future generations

Comment: Hi. If it solved your question, it would be great if you could accept my answer.